# PHP is_file() and file_exists() doesn't return true for existing PDF and SVG files

Tags: php, pdf, file-handling, file-exists

I don't know if this is an intrinsic property of the functions or something in my PHP configuration, but for some reason when I am using is_file() and file_exists() to confirm the existence of a PDF or SVG file with a global path (/home/brian/public_html/path/to/file.pdf) then it will return false even if the file is there.

Is there a reason this would happen for these filetypes?

Comment: No, it would happen if PHP couldn't access those files e.g. the permissions are wrong.

Comment: Permissions are the same for all the files in that dir (644). Yet PHP can access the .png and .jpgs no problem.

Comment: You've checked the same upper/lower case used for all the letters?

Comment: Yes.  I'm literally copying and pasting filenames from the dir into the test script.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the the problem right away and found no other solution than using fopen():

```
if ($file = @fopen($file_path, 'rb')): // returns resource id if file exists
   //do whatever you like!
else:
   //file does not exist
endif;
```

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but it works for me

Comment: Rated up on this as it is a solution however I think file_exists needs to use a file path, not a URL.